# Aos.js content not showing up when scroll into view

Tags: animation, scrollview, aos.js

I have read similar issues about this [here](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos/issues/110). But none of the suggested solutions worked for me.

What I have found from inspection is that the class `aos-animate` is not added to the animating element, and I can see the class `aos-init` in the element.

The element can animate if I do the following:

1. resize the windows
2. manually add aos-animate to the element in inspection
3. the element is in viewport when the page is refreshed.

This looks like a bug in `aos.js`.